# Holomorphic function on boundary implies derivative is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is a question that I was attempting while preparing for an entrance exam:

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be bounded, open and connected. Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to  \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on $D$ and continous on $D\cup \partial D$ and for every $z\in \partial D$, we have $|f(z)|\leq 1$. Let $p(z)$ be the distance from $z$ to $\partial D$. Prove that $|f'(z)|\leq 1/p(z)$.

The setup makes me think of using Cauchy Integral formula (and the bound that comes from it) but I couldn't get that to work easily. I tried examining the proof of said theorem, but I couldn't see where to go. I would love just a small hint to get me going. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

$|f(z)| \le 1$ on $\partial D$ implies $|f(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in D$, because of the maximum modulus principle.

If $z \in D$ and $0 < r < p(z)$ then the disk $B_r(z)$ is contained in $D$ and we can apply the Cauchy integral formula for the derivative:
$$
 f'(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i } \int_{|\zeta - z| = r} \frac{f(z)}{(\zeta -z)^2} \, dz \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
|f'(z)| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{|\zeta - z| = r} \frac{|f(z)|}{|\zeta -z|^2} \, |dz| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{|\zeta - z| = r} \frac{1}{r^2} \, |dz| = \frac{1}{r} \, .
$$
Now take the limit for $r \to p(z)$ to conclude that
$$
|f'(z)|  \le \frac{1}{p(z)} \, .
$$

---

Alternatively use that for fixed $z \in D$ the function $g: \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$ defined as
$$
 g(w) = \frac 12 \bigl( f(z+p(z)w) - f(z-p(z)w)\bigr)
$$
satisfies $g(0) = 0$ and $|g'(w)| \le 1$. The Schwarz lemma gives that
$$
 1 \ge |g'(0)| = p(z) |f'(z)| \, .
$$

Comment: Upvoted. Your first display line with Cauchy’s integral formula should read $f'(z)$. You were missing the stroke.

Comment: @k.stm: You are right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I had the idea of copying the proof of Schwarz lemma: consider the function $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$$ and apply maximum modulus principle. However, I can only get $|f’(a)|\le 2/p(z)$. Do you have any idea how I could make this approach work?

Comment: @Szeto: See update.

Comment: @MartinR thanks!